# VB.NET Function - Return vs Assignment

Tags: vb.net, function

What is the difference between this two ways of returning value in a function in VB.NET?

Using Return Statement:

```
Public Function Foo() As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function
```

Using Assignment:

```
Public Function Foo() As String
    Foo = "Hello World"
End Function
```

I'm using the first one then I saw someone using the second. I wonder if there's a benefit I could get using the second.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its a legacy carry over from basic days.

`Return` will leave the scope immediately, while assignment wont.

Answer (score 7):

Think of it this way:

```
Public Function Foo() As String
    Foo = "Hello World"
    OtherFunctionWithSideEffect()
End Function
```

vs

```
Public Function Foo() As String
    Return "Hello World"
    OtherFunctionWithSideEffect()
End Function
```

Now can you see the difference?

In practice, modern VB.Net should almost always prefer the latter style (`Return`).

Comment: That is actually incorrect since in the first function OtherFunctionWithSideEffect will execute and in the second it will not. Which could be considered a + for option number one. In this case.

Comment: @chrissie Joel's point is that in the first function OtherFunctionWithSideEffect will execute and in the second it will not

Comment: @chrissie1 - of course they're different. That's the whole point.

Answer (score 6):

Testing this in LinqPad:

```
Public Function myString() As String    
    Return "Hello World"
End Function

Public Function myString2() As String
    myString2 = "Hello World"
End Function
```

Here's the IL output:

```
myString:
IL_0000:  ldstr       "Hello World"
IL_0005:  ret         

myString2:
IL_0000:  ldstr       "Hello World"
IL_0005:  stloc.0     
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     
IL_0007:  ret
```

So in a sense the IL would add two more lines but this is a small diffence i think.

Answer (score 5):

Both are valid but using `Return` saves having to add `Exit Function` if you want to return part way through a function so it is preferable:

```
If param.length=0 then
    Msgbox "Invalid parameter length"
    Return Nothing
End If
```

Compare with:

```
If param.length=0 then
    Msgbox "Invalid parameter length"
    Foo = Nothing
    Exit Function
End If
```

Also If you use `Return` you don't have to remember to right click Rename to rename all instances of Foo to FooNew if you decide to change the name of your function.

Answer (score 2):

Alongside the other answers, there is also a difference, as follows:

```
Public Function Test() As Integer
  Try
    Dim retVal as Integer = 0
    retVal = DoSomethingExceptional()
  Catch ex as Exception ' bad practice, I know
  Finally
  Test = retVal
  End Try
End Function
```

You can't put a Return in a Finally block, but you can assign the value of the function there.